# React Context API - One provider, multiple consumers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to get used to the Context API functionality of React, and what I'm trying to do is to consume the context provided in one component in 2 other components. Unfortunately, when trying to access the context in the second context consumer, the *value* of the **context** is `undefined`. How can I solve this?

`Provider (snippet)`:

```
const [loginState, changeLoginState] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    login: () => {}
  });

  const loginHandler = () => {
    let newState = {...loginState};
    newState.isAuthenticated = true;
    changeLoginState(newState);
  };

  return (
    <div className={CSSmodule.App}>

    <AuthContext.Provider value = { {
      isAuthenticated: loginState.isAuthenticated,
      login: loginHandler
    } }>

      <Cockpit 
        showValuesState = {showValuesState}
        showContent = {showContent}
        personsStateLength = {personsState.length}/>

    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

`Consumer 1 (works)`:

```
<AuthContext.Consumer>
         {
              (context) => {
                    console.log("[Cockpit.js]", context);   
                        return (
                            <button
                                onClick = {context.login}>
                                     Login
                            </button>
                        ); 
               }
         }
</AuthContext.Consumer>
```

`Consumer 2 (context value is undefined)`:

```
<AuthContext.Consumer>
     {
            (context) => {
                console.log("[from Person.js]", context);
                if(context.isAuthenticated)
                      return (<p>Authenticated!</p>);
             }
     }
</AuthContext.Consumer>
```

`Imported AuthContext component from context.js`:

```
import React from "react";

const context = React.createContext();

export default context;
```

Comment: Mind sharing your code?

Comment: @PsyGik added the most important parts.

Comment: Is `Cockpit` your top most component in your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Context is only available to its descendants

The way context sharing works is that all your components which needs to access the context
data must be wrapped within a single provider.

```
<Context.Provider value={}>
    <App/>
</Context.Provider>
```

In the above snippet, `App` is the top most component. The hierarchy is:

```
App
|-- Home
|-- About
```

Now `Home` and `About` can access values from the Context.

---

In your code, `Person.js` is probably not rendered as a descendant of the `<AuthContext.Provider>`, so it can't get access to it. In other words, the provider should "enclose" the consumers. [From the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components [...]

Comment: The tree is as follows: App -- PersonList & Cockpit, while PersonList uses Person. The Provider is App, while the consumers are Cockpit and Person (which is child component for PersonList). So the consumers are descendants, even though not direct ones.

Comment: In your sample code, `AuthContext.Provider` has `Cockpit` as it's descendant.

Comment: Ohhh, thats' what you meant. I included PersonList as descendant and it works, thank you!